# How to delete zero elements in a csr_matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am doing some sparse matrix calculation with python using csr_matrix from scipy.sparse. There will be many zero elements produced, stored as 0.0. How can I delete these elements to save memory usage?

I've tried the 'eliminate_zeros' function, but it's not working.

When I print the sparse matrix, the first several elements are:

```
  (0, 0)    5.0
  (0, 1)    -1.05
  (1, 0)    -1.05
  (1, 1)    2.0
  (0, 2)    -1.05
  (0, 3)    0.0
  (1, 2)    0.0
```

The 0.0 comes from calculation like 0.5-0.5.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Saving data in sparse format is particularly useful when there are mostly zero entries, or as its name suggests, the matrix is *sparse*

Comment: Try `M.data==0` to see whether those 0's you see really are zero.  With floating point testing exactly for 0 can be tricky.

Comment: To add to my comment, `eliminate_zeros` only works on values that are exactly 0; not just ones that are close.  You may need to massage the `M.data` values first to find ones that are close (within some tolerance) and set them to 0.  Don't count on floating point subtraction to do that for you.

Comment: @yatu The matrix is large (ideally I want it to be 2^20*2^20) and sparse (most elements are 0, as you mentioned).

Comment: @hpaulj Yes it works if I set them to 0 and it's not so costing as I thought. Thank you very much.